# angular unit test, method has already been spied upon issue after updating into angular9

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular9

I just updated my angular app into version 9. Everything works fine excluding the unit tests. After updating, the unit tests not working.

Below is my sample test suite

```
   describe("test Component", () => {
     beforeEach(async(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
        ],
        providers: [ 
            { provide: InitService, useValue: mockInit },
            { provide: ControlsService, useValue: genericMock },
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
       }).compileComponents();
     }));
      it('should initialize slides', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        const slides = TestBed.inject(SlideChangeService);
        const controls = TestBed.inject(ControlsService);
       
        spyOn(slides, 'initialize');
        spyOn(controls, 'initialize');

        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(slides.initialize).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(controls.initialize).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
   });
```

it works fine before the angular updation, but now it shows below error!!!

```
Error: <spyOn> : initialize has already been spied upon
```

so, how we can spy on two different services that using same method name in angular9 unit tests?

Comment: why are you not testing `component.SlideChangeService.itsMethod`  and replacing using `useClass` rather than injecting actual service. Also, I dont you would need `fixture.whenStable()`. is it really mandatory ?  On side note, you can refer https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49 to get an idea of using `stubs` and how to test methods being called